# get only one part of my let in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, class, swift4

I need some help with my app. 
so, 
I have this code

```
let let1 = Autosteiger(name: "Name1", addres: "Straat 1", coordinates: "coordinaten 1")
let let2 = Autosteiger(name: "Name 2", addres: "Straat 2", coordinates: "Coordinated 2")
```

and I want only the name as a **String** in my array

PS
"Autosteiger" is a swift file a mode, I am not sure how to call it. 
code "Autosteiger" (It's a different file!)

```
import UIKit

class Autosteiger {
    var name: String
    var addres: String
    let coordinates: String
    var image: UIImage

init(name: String, addres: String, coordinates: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.addres = addres
    self.coordinates = coordinates

    image = UIImage(named: self.name)!
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: It is unclear from your question what you want to do. Where is this array you are talking about?

Comment: The first question regading the array is not clear and it has no connection from the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am supposing you have an array of your `Autosteiger` model.

```
let let1 = Autosteiger(name: "Name1", addres: "Straat 1", coordinates: "coordinaten 1")
let let2 = Autosteiger(name: "Name 2", addres: "Straat 2", coordinates: "Coordinated 2")

let modalArray = [let1, let2]
```

And you want an array with the name properties of all models. So you can it like this:

```
let nameArray = modalArray.map { $0.name }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: now I got another problem, it's outside the viewdidload function.